# How do you get Blender to load thumbnails for the asset browser

Tags: materials, asset, asset-browser

[image: This is what Blender shows me in the asset browser]

I need to see the thumbnails for my materials but they won't load

Comment: I’m voting to close this question as off topic because it is about troubleshooting temporary issues with unfinished under development experimental versions of software, which are expected to be working properly upon stable release. This produces a question unlikely to be useful for future users, rendering its long term value low, making it unsuited for this site.

Comment: Might be the same problem as here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244909/blender-3-asset-browser-slow-unreliably-loads-material-previews/245459#245459 : You didn't wait long enough before quitting the file after you marked the materials as asset. Unmark and remark them, then wait for it to be completed