# Blender 3 Asset Browser slow? Unreliably loads material previews?

Tags: asset, asset-browser

I'm using Blender 3.0 for the first time and I'm especially excited by the Asset Browser. I'm currently adding my library of materials, but an issue I'm running into is that getting the Asset Browser to display material thumbnail previews is hit and miss; **why aren't there previews for all the materials I've marked as assets?**

Hitting the refresh icon doesn't help, however sometimes I'll check the Asset Browser at a later time and several more materials will have thumbnail previews, but not all of them. Does the Asset Browser take a looooooong time to generate the previews? Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.0.0 Windows 10

[image]

Comment: Is your RAM full?

Comment: I've got plenty of RAM (32 GB). I think the issue has to do with how I'm designating some of the materials as assets. If I mark a group of materials as assets via Display Mode > Blender File > Materials, the previews are missing from the Asset Browser; however, if I mark an individual material as an asset via Material Properties, the preview shows up. While the latter method works, that could be tedious as I have hundreds of materials I'd like to catalog.

Comment: I assume these materials are from a different file. I've seen this myself. What happens is that when you select "Mark as asset" blender starts rendering the previews in the background one by one. If you close the blend-file containing the materials before Blender has finished rendering the previews, they'll be missing. So, just reopen the original file that contains your materials. Unmark and remark them as assets and wait until rendering has finished. (Observe CPU usage to get an indication.)

Comment: That's the answer, michaelh. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just reposting the answer which was given in the comments by [michaelh](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/24921/michaelh) for closure :

> I assume these materials are from a different file. I've seen this
> myself. What happens is that when you select "Mark as asset" blender
> starts rendering the previews in the background one by one. If you
> close the blend-file containing the materials before Blender has
> finished rendering the previews, they'll be missing. So, just reopen
> the original file that contains your materials. Unmark and remark them
> as assets and wait until rendering has finished. (Observe CPU usage to
> get an indication.)