# New Blender 3.0 asset manager outputting purple thumbnails

Tags: asset

New Blender 3.0 asset manager outputting purple thumbnails. All meshes and materials are rendering correctly in viewport. All textures have been packed on the blend file.
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/om3ja4z9ksa4jri/Test_ISO.blend?dl=0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Don't know whether this might apply here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244909/blender-3-asset-browser-slow-unreliably-loads-material-previews?rq=1

Comment: This is a a bug and it's already being worked on. The normal map of your shader is used instead of the principled. See this video :  https://youtu.be/wzI20KIFK_k or this post : https://blenderartists.org/t/asset-browser-utilities-batch-mark-unmark-assets-from-library-export-assets-to-a-new-file/1343899/16